# enable aws commands in slack using chatbot

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have enabled chatbot as explained in the tutorial.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chatbot/latest/adminguide/setting-up.html

It works as expected most of the times. But I get an error "**command not enabled**" for a few services in slack. For e.g. I can't run the command s3 get-object because it isn't enabled. While the "@aws s3 list-buckets" command works as expected. None of the redshift related commands are working. What do I need to do to "enable" all commands?

Where can I see the supported commands?

---

Update:

More examples:

```
@aws redshift-data list-databases --cluster-identifier xxx --db-user root --database dev

@user I can't run the command redshift-data list-databases because it isn't enabled.
```

Certain read-only commands like @aws s3 list-buckets works as expected. But other commands do not work. For e.g. I am not able to start or stop an ec2 instance from slack. I do not want to use slack commands for "read-only" access.